# GM.getValue is undefined

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I write a small userscript and it was first only for one webpage, now that I added more functions I try to let the script work over multiple sites and as far as I understand I have to go from `localStorage` to `GM.getValue`, but won't get it to work.
I allready learned that the functions is async and I have to use it. So to get this functions to know better, I wrote a lil' testscript and have still no success - so maybe someone might help me.

I get GM.setValue to work, so if I check in Tampermokey the script-tag I see that I have for this script in storage:

```
{
    "WFP_token": "123456789"
}
```

and the userscript is

```
// @grant           GM.getValue
// @grant           GM.setValue
// @grant           GM_getValue
// @grant           GM_setValue
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    /**
    * Overall script parts are placed here
    */
    console.log('[WFP]: init');

    function getToken() {
        (async () => {
            let token = GM.getValue("WFP_token",-1);
            if (token != -1 && token != undefined) {
                return token;
            } else {
                window.setTimeout(getToken(),10)
            }
        })();
    }
    const WEBHOOK_TOKEN = getToken();
    console.log('[WFP]: '+WEBHOOK_TOKEN);
```

the console output is:

```
[WFP]: init
[WFP]: undefined
```

Can somebody help me and point me where I'm wrong and who I should use `GM.getValue`?

Comment: Remove `()` so it becomes `setTimeout(getToken, 10)`

Comment: changed that, but unfortunately it has no effect to the final result

Comment: Ah, that's because asynchronous code doesn't return anything. You need `await GM.getValue` and move the second console.log to replace `return token;` so it'll look like `console.log(token)`

Comment: You missed `await`, see my updated comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use await near `GM.getValue`, `getToken()` and return a promise in `setTimeout` else case

```js
(async function() {
  'use strict';
  /**
   * Overall script parts are placed here
   */
  console.log('[WFP]: init');

  async function getToken(a) {
    let token = await GM.getValue("WFP_token", -1);
    if (token != -1 && token != undefined) {
      return token;
    } else {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        window.setTimeout(() => resolve(getToken()), 10);
      })
    }
  }

  const WEBHOOK_TOKEN = await getToken();
  console.log('[WFP]: ' + WEBHOOK_TOKEN);
})();
```

Comment: thanks, works for me, with the full asyc-stuff, I could also remove the loop-check

now I will see and try to get it work with my other code

Comment: await doesn't solve the 'TypeError: GM.getValue is not a function' in FF89/GM4.11.

Answer (score 0):

While Nagesh's answer is correct, there's one more thing missing:

**Make sure you have `@grant GM.getValue` in the metadata block!**

After doing that, make sure your function is asynchronous.

OP did not forget this step, but I did, and finally found the solution on the [developer's blog](https://www.greasespot.net/2017/09/greasemonkey-4-for-script-authors.html). Hope this helps anybody coming to this question.